# File parsing code need attention

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, parsing, file-io

I have a file like this

```
I am a student xyz in university"|USA|" in first year.
I am a student abc in university"|America|" in first year.
I am a student asd in university"|Italy|" in first year.
```

I have to parse the file and extract only the university name from the file and also the xyz,abc,asd
so i have written the following code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
bool ParseLine(const std::string& line, std::string& key, std::string& value);

class Demo
{
public:
    typedef struct _Data 
    {
        std::string university;
        std::string name;

    } Data;

    Data data;
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("Ca.txt");
    std::string line;
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    Demo obj;
    while(!ifs.eof())
    {
        std::getline(ifs, line);
        if (ParseLine(line, key, value))
        {
            if (0 == key.compare("student"))
            {
                obj.data.name = value;
            }

             else if (0 == key.compare("university"))
            {
                obj.data.content = value;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr<<"Unknow key:" << key << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool ParseLine(const std::string& line, std::string& key, std::string& value)
{
    bool flag = false;

    if (line.find("//") != 0)
    {
        size_t pos = line.find("|");
        if (pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            key = line.substr(0, pos);
             size_t pos1 = line.find(";");
            value = line.substr(pos + 1, pos1);
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Two problems
When extracting the university value i get every thing like "USA|" in first year" but i want only USA and name logic dosen't work

Please guide

Comment: What is `obj.data.content`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 it should be obj.data.university  sorry my mistake

Comment: Well `ParseLine` doesn't look like it's doing the right thing. What is `key` and `value` meant to hold?

Comment: @0x499602D2 value holds the final output suppose if we send university in key then value should hold USA,if you think above code is not good you please share some other pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

I would try to read the stream word-wise, and check for appropriate names and university:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("Ca.txt");
    std::string line, word;
    Demo obj;

    while (std::getline(ifs, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        while (iss >> word)
        {
            if ((word == "student") && iss >> word)
            {
                obj.data.name = word;
            } else if (word.find("university") != std::string::npos)
            {
                size_t pos1 = word.find_first_of("|"),
                       pos2 = word.find_last_of("|");

                obj.data.university = word.substr(pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1);
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Name: "       << obj.data.name << "\n"
                  << "University: " << obj.data.university << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: will it have the name correct i mean xyz and abc and another thing you have written word.substr(10); but i think we should find this |" in the code as it would not be 10 always sometimes more or less than 10.what u say

Comment: @user3340847 It should be correct. Give me a second to test it.

Comment: @user3340847 Sorry I took so long. I was able to get it to work. I will update my answer.

Comment: i am getting this error error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Elem &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&' from 'int'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1028) : see declaration of 'std::operator >>'  specially on iss and >>

Comment: some more error error C2079: 'iss' uses undefined class 'std::basic_istringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>c:\users\batra\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sig_parse\sig_parse\parse.cpp(149): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'int'

Comment: @user3340847 Did you `#include <sstream>`?

Comment: the code works exactly fine but a some problem if i change the above line as I am a student xyz in university"|USA Europe|" in first year. it only prints University as USA not as USA EUROPE